# Associated App ID was not transferred to the recipient’s Member Center account after an app was successfully transfered

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW13) says:

> After an app is transferred, its associated App ID is also transferred to the recipient’s Member Center account.

In my case it didn't happen. Why?

I transferred the app with success, but on recipient's Member Center account there is no the App ID of trasferred App.

Comment: did you solve this problem ? how ? What did you do ?

Comment: Haven't solved it yet.

Comment: Looks like a bug, contact Apple. I recently tranfered an app without any problem